# Rails 4 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column--ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and doing upgrade from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.0. I keep hitting the following error which I never saw before the upgrade:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'report_fields.id' in 'order clause': SELECT rrf.* FROM `report_fields` JOIN report_types rrt ON rrt.id = rrf.report_type_id WHERE (rrt.name = 'Creturn' AND rrf.name = 'Root Cause') ORDER BY `report_fields`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

I've looked at several related posts on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution. Most of them are doing [db changes/migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828983/rails3-mysql2error-unknown-column-activerecordstatementinvalid) but I'm **NOT** changing anything in the tables.

When I run show table command on the report_fields table I can see the id field is right there. I just don't understand why it can't be found.

```
show fields from report_fields;

Field           Type           Null Key Default  Extra
id              int(11)        NO   PRI          auto_increment
report_type_id  int(11)        NO   MUL     
name            varchar(255)   NO           
parent_id       int(11)        YES  MUL     
display_order   smallint(6)    NO           0
```

The ReportField class:

```
class ReportField < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tree

    has_many :report_field_values
    has_many :report_field_options, -> { order(:value) }

    belongs_to :researchable_report_type

    # THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR COMES FROM
    def self.find_field_for_report_type(report_type, field_name)
        return ReportField.find(
         :first,
         :select => "rrf.*",
         :joins => "AS rrf
                    JOIN report_types rrt
                        ON rrt.id = rrf.report_type_id",
         :conditions => ["rrt.name = ? AND rrf.name = ?",
                          report_type, field_name])
end
```

The ReportType class:

```
class ReportType < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :report_fields, -> { order(:display_order) }

    def self.load_by_name(rrt_name,report_name = nil)
        self.find(:first,
              :include => [:report_fields => :report_field_options],
              :conditions => {:name => rrt_name,:report_name => report_name})
    end
........
end
```

I know that Rails 4 deprecated quite a few finder methods so I have the Gem "activerecord-deprecated_finders" included in the Gemfile but it's probably unrelated...

What could be the root cause of this issue? Where should I look into?

**Update:**
Theoretically the activerecord-deprecated_finders gem should enable the old finder methods but just in case, I rewrote the query using Rails 4 but I still hit similar errors.

The new query:

```
def self.find_field_for_report_type(report_type, field_name)
        return ReportField.joins("JOIN report_types ON report_types.id = report_field.report_type_id")
                           .where("report_types.name = '#{report_type}' AND report_field.name = '#{field_name}'")
                           .first
end
```

This time it complains about unknown column 'name' in the report_fields table. Again, the name column is there...

More Updates:
Calling ReportFields.last and print it out, I have the following log:

```
[DEBUG] ReportField Load (69.0ms)  SELECT `report_fields`.* FROM `report_fields` ORDER BY `report_fields`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
[INFO] #<ReportField:0x007fa271514e18>#<ReportField:0x007fa271514e18>
[INFO] 200, Action Required
```

**Updates 2016-08-16**
It looks like this has something to do with the table alias. When I take out the table alias, the query actually works. Not sure what is happening...

```
def self.find_field_for_report_type(report_type, field_name)
     return ReportField.find(
            :first,
            :select => "*",
            :joins => "JOIN report_types
                           ON report_types.id = report_fields.report_type_id",
            :conditions => ["report_types.name = ? AND report_fields.name = ?",
                             report_type, field_name])
end
```

Comment: As you come to Rails 4, first rewrite those query Rails 4 way. And then test again.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I did try that but it throws similar errors. Please see my updates.

Comment: Can you do `ReportField.last` and show me what you see?

Comment: I don't see the log. Don't put them in comments, rather in your question.

Comment: What is your actual model name? I see `ResearchableReport‌​Field` and you are saying it as `ReportField` model.

Comment: Show the exact error when you run this `find_field_for_report_type` method.

Comment: @ArupRakshit sorry I was just trying to mask the class name a bit. Please just treat the ResearchableReport‌‌​​Field as Report‌‌​​Field...Anyway the id column and name column exist and I can print it out. It seems that the failure has something to do with join?

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand. I said you to show me it in Rails console in your development machine though. From which environment you got those logs btw?

Comment: @ArupRakshit We have an isolated host running on Production and it was first found there. To reproduce it on development we have to change eager_load to true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120999/discussion-between-steelwingsjz-and-arup-rakshit).